# Programmatically get active connections in windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I would like to get all active connections (similar to TCPView from sysinternals) on a windows machine, using WinAPI.

How can I do this using Winsock ?

Comment: Can the down voter please explain himself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winsock does not provide any functionality to get a list of active connections.

The [`GetTcpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetTcp6Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309068(v=vs.85).aspx), and [`GetTcp6Table2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405(v=vs.85).aspx) functions of the  [IP Helper API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073(v=vs.85).aspx) provide the information that you are looking for.